# HTML inside a function

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have this code:

```
<?php $call = 'i want to show HTML here';?>

<?php echo $call;?>
```

i tryed:

```
<?php $call = '<p>SHOW HTML</p>';?>
```

also

```
<?php $call = '.'<p>SHOW HTML</p>'.';?>
```

also

```
<?php $call = "<p>SHOW HTML</p>";?>
```

also

```
<?php $call = <p>SHOW HTML</p>;?>
```

but nothing works for me

Comment: `$call = '<p>SHOW HTML</p>';` is fine, as is the double quote version. You need to `echo $call;` to display it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Your code should work fine in the first *I tried* example

Comment: Do you want to *show* the HTML or *render* it?  What you tried first works fine to render it.  If you want to show the HTML code on the page, you need to HTML encode it first.

Comment: maybe it's because i am echo it in a jquery "text" ? this is the code: jQuery('.art-headline').text('<?php echo $call;?>');

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's `.html()` instead of `.text()`?

Comment: o ! i see. when i changed the "text" to "html" it worked

Comment: yup, .text() is strictly for text strings, no html at all.  .html() is for any html content.

Comment: Please update the question to show the jQuery call that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are generating HTML with PHP and passing it to jQuery's [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function which only renders text, not HTML. Instead, use jQuery's [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

Comment: Would have been nice if OP had mentioned that...lol

Answer (score 0):

Try using htmlspecialchars function

```
<?php $call = $call = "<p>SHOW HTML</p>";   

echo htmlspecialchars($call);

?>
```

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what he wants.

Comment: I think that he want to show htm code not render it

Comment: He wants to render it with jQuery. See his comment: _when i changed the "text" to "html" it worked_